# Get image and title from viewpager on buttonclick

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager. There is a button layout. When a user clicks on it, it should give the data from the current image. But it gives the title from the next image.

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

        imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
        imageViewPreview.setOnTouchListener(new ImageMatrixTouchHandler(view.getContext()));
        Photos image = images.get(position);

        img_title = image.getTitle();


        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(image.getUrl())
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.loader))
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(imageViewPreview);
        Button  save_img = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save_img);
        save_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), img_title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        share_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                shareImage(view);
            }
        });


        container.addView(view);
        return view;

    }
```

**How can I get the title from the *current* image?**

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the right position when calling this method?

Comment: how can i pass position in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ViewPager initializes three objects: an object at the current position, an object from the previous position and an object from the next position. And as I see you update the img_title each time and object is initializing

```
img_title = image.getTitle();
```

All what you have to do is make it a local variable:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

        imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
        imageViewPreview.setOnTouchListener(new ImageMatrixTouchHandler(view.getContext()));
        Photos image = images.get(position);

        final String img_title = image.getTitle();


        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(image.getUrl())
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.loader))
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(imageViewPreview);
        Button  save_img = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save_img);
        save_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), img_title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        share_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                shareImage(view);
            }
        });


        container.addView(view);
        return view;

    }
```

Comment: it's working . how can i pass the imageview like this ?

Comment: @Mukesh Soni
 Also make it a local variable

final ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);